# Allow download of entire contents of Amazon S3 folder in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm using Django and I have a S3 Account with files in a folder called media. I want to allow users to download the entire list of files as an archived zip folder to save them having to click on each individual link to get the file.

I'm using Django, and Amazon S3 and Boto3. Links are like,

```
https://mydomain.s3.amazonaws.com/media/filename1.txt
https://mydomain.s3.amazonaws.com/media/filename2.txt
https://mydomain.s3.amazonaws.com/media/filename3.txt
https://mydomain.s3.amazonaws.com/media/filename4.txt
https://mydomain.s3.amazonaws.com/media/filename5.txt
```

So essential I want to bundle all files in another link that is a download to all files, as an archive.

Any suggestions on how to do this with Django?

Comment: for accessing each file, you can use S3 Presigned URLs. For downloading as an archive, you will need to write python code to download multiple files and archive it

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow access to a file stored in s3, you can generate a s3 pre-signed URL, that will give specific access(read or write) to the file. Each Url generated gives access to exactly one file. The access is granted only for a certain time (maximum 7 days). this is the most recommended approach. if you dont want the Url to expire, you will need to create a django route that downloads the file for the user.

In order to download files as archive, you need to create a django route,  such as `/downloadAll?user=1`. When the user visit to the url, you need to download files from s3 using and create the archive.

Comment: I decided to write the contents of each of these files into one big file and allow that for download and archiving on the user's side. The main problem with implementing the archiving, was opening the file from Amazon's S3 side and writing the contents of that file into a zip file, which would have been returned as a HttpResponse with the type 'application/zip' in the response.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a management task in django to avoid the long wait on the page, so that once these files are created you can run the management task.

```
python manage.py archive_files

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = ''
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        self.stdout.write("doing")
        write_archive_file()
        self.stdout.write("done")
```

With the archive file created, I can then make that downloadable.